# PHP & mySQL: Query table to see if date + IP combination exists

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date, timestamp

I have this PHP contact form which disallows a submission from an existing IP. I am trying to add the feature to submit one entry per IP, per day.

I have a column in my db table called Date which is datestamping every row. I know I need to create my if statement with 2 conditions... I am just not sure how to check the DB before submitting a new entry. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

CODE SNIPPET:

```
$ip = gethostbyname($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
$QUERY = "SELECT COUNT(IP) AS `count` FROM `contest` WHERE IP = '$ip'";
$RESULT = mysql_query($QUERY) or die(mysql_error());

// Read the firs row
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($RESULT);

// Check how many rows MySQL counted
if($row['count'] > 0) {
header ('Location: valueexists.html');
}
else {

//save the data on the DB

mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

$insert_query = sprintf("INSERT INTO contest (Name, Email_Address, Phone, Company_Name, Company_Address, Date, ip) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, NOW(), %s)",
```

Comment: are you sure you certainly understands what is gethostbyname() function for?

Comment: I believe so: to resolve a hostname by IP address, so people don't submit multiple submissions.

Comment: well, it seems you are wrong. this function does not resolve a hostname by IP address, and I see no point in such resolving in general. Why IP address itself doesn't suit you?

Comment: gethostbyaddr() or getaddrinfo() would be more fitting?

Comment: no. none of these you need. `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` already contains an IP address. no need to apply any function

Comment: makes perfect sense... changed to $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure is correct, to make a query with two conditions, simply add a **AND** to it:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(ip) AS count FROM contest WHERE ip = '$ip' AND DATE(date) = CURDATE()";
```

This will count all rows in the **contest** table with that IP and which have been submitted on that specific date. Note that I took "date" as your fieldname as I'm unaware of your table structure, so adapt it to the one you created.

**Edit**
I just noticed you are using `NOW()` to store your datetime in your database, so I changed my query to make use of the `DATE()` function. This extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression of the value as can be seen [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I changed your query to make it less verbose and more readable

Comment: Thanks Col Shrapnel!
Tinkering with this now... Currently returning an echo of "Query was empty"..

Comment: @user that means query was empty. may be you need to write it in your unusual manner - in the upper case $QUERY

Comment: hmmm... I think you solved this issue for me. Only I changed your > to a =

so if the date is EQUAL to todays date, don't submit

$QUERY = "SELECT COUNT(ip) AS count FROM contest WHERE ip = '$ip' AND `DATE` = CURDATE()";

Comment: @silenc3xx Ye apparently silenc3xx changed my query to something incorrect. Please only modify answers if you can improve them. The `DATE(date)` is there for a reason as I explained.

Comment: You mean Col. Shrapnel changed your query, not me... I just updated the file with your code and it seems to be working perfectly. Thanks for all of the help Jules & Col. Shrapnel.

Comment: Why is Shrapnel's method not as correct? It was working properly once I changed ">" to "=".... CODE: $QUERY = "SELECT COUNT(ip) AS count FROM contest WHERE ip = '$ip' AND `DATE` = CURDATE()";

Comment: @silenc3xx: Sorry, yes I meant Col. Shrapnel, not you. My bad.. : )
Yes, he changed = to > which is not the right solution. I didn't expect you could compare a DateTime to a Date as one is more precise. But glad it solved your problem. Please tick it as correct. :-)

Comment: @Jules Thanks for the solution and explanation. This is why I love this site. I've ticked it as correct. Have a good one :)

Answer (score -1):

You are going to want to do something similar to:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contest WHERE IP ='".$IP."'"));

if($count > 0) {
$error = '<div class="error_message">Sorry, username already taken.</div>';
}
```

Simply put, you are just querying the database to see if an IP exists, mind you this should probably be wrapped in a `if(isset($_POST['add_user'])) { }` to detect if the form was indeed submitted by this form ID alone.

Comment: which question this piece of text answers to?

Comment: I already have this part solved... I need to check the IP as well as the date.

In a nutshell: Check row for existing IP && current date... IF it exists, don't submit. I want multiple submissions just not if it's on the same date.

Comment: well "I am just trying to help" is not an excuse. A help should be sensible and somewhat relevant one.

Answer (score -2):

you can use strtotime('midnight') to get the timestamp of the start of today. When you include this in the query you make sure that mysql only returns entries from today:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(ip) AS count FROM contest WHERE ip = '$ip' AND DATE > " . strtotime('midnight');
```

Comment: this is quite cunning way of doing things.